# TPC-H schema and data someone has?

Tags: postgresql, benchmarking, tpc

Has someone the TPC-H schema?
I try to compile but has some errors.

I need the sql schema file.
And if possible the data sql file.

Thanks

Comment: I've found the  Visual TPC-H that allow to generate the TPC-H data, adn modify the eschema. It's was the best solution, instead DBGen.

Answer (score 1):

TPC-H have a DBGEN that generates a database.

You can see at : http://www.tpc.org/tpch/

Answer (score 1):

I maintain a repo of the data generator and schema here: https://bitbucket.org/tkejser/tpch-dbgen. It is a bit nicer to work with than the one from TPC.

There is a postgres ready schema in the repo as well as a makefile that does The Right Thing for Postgres.